# Use Print() to print more than 8000 characters

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql

How can I print a string (e.g. a dynamic query) that contains more than 8000 chars?

```
Declare @sql varchar(max)
set @Qry='....(more than 8000 char)'
Print (@Qry)
```

The above only prints the first 8000 characters of @Qry and cuts off the rest.

Comment: Print (CAST(@Qry as TEXT))

Comment: That's it!!...thanks bro...it works great for me.

Comment: There is still a restriction on the output to the text, but it is regulated by the setting SSMS

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that VARCHAR(MAX) holds up to 2gb of data, but print() only prints 8000, characters to the terminal.  So you have to break up your string into 8000 char chunks and print them separately.  e.g.

```
declare @test varchar(max);
declare @loop int = 1;
declare @length int =0;
declare @printed int =0;

/*build an exceptionally long string.*/
set @test= 'select ''1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000''';

while @loop < 1001 
begin
     set @test = @test + ',''12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890''';
     set @loop = @loop + 1;

end;
/*!build an exceptionally long string.*/

set @length = len(@test);
while @printed < @length
BEGIN
    print(substring(@test,@printed,8000));
    set @printed = @printed + 8000; 
END
```

Comment: If trying to print an `NVARCHAR` instead, the loops are in 4000's instead of 8000, due to `NVARCHAR` occupying 2 bytes per character instead of 1 and the print's limit is still 8000 bytes (4000 characters).

Answer (score -1):

```
declare 
   @msg nvarchar(max)
  ,@zeile nvarchar(500)
  ,@laenge bigint=0
  ,@aus bigint=0
  ,@nxt bigint=0

--select * from Monitor.PROMON01 with(nolock) where programm='Entwicklung'
select info from Monitor.PROMON01 with(nolock) where id='53236049-128E-44DE-8AA0-4B7F6247A3F8'
select @msg=info from Monitor.PROMON01 with(nolock) where id='53236049-128E-44DE-8AA0-4B7F6247A3F8'

set @laenge = len(@msg);
while @aus < @laenge
BEGIN
    set @nxt=CHARINDEX(char(13)+char(10),@msg,@nxt)
    set @zeile=substring(@msg,@aus,iif(@nxt-@aus>0,@nxt-@aus,0));
    print @zeile
    set @aus += LEN(@zeile)+2; 
    set @nxt+=2
END
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).